# Como Devolver un objeto con los pares clave-valor intercambiados

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

necesitaría ayuda porque no puedo llegar a encontrar la solución. Lo que necesito es devolver un objeto con los pares clave-valor intercambiados. Por ejemplo:

intercambio({ nombre: "Homero", apellido: "Simpson" }); devuelve => { Homero: "nombre", Simpson: "apellido" }

**El problema es que no debo utilizar estos métodos de Object (values, keys, entries)**

Como lo deberia encarar? Porque pense en hacer un for para recorrer el objeto pero no se como seguir...

Mil gracias!

Comment: Para poder ayudarte debes mostrar lo que has intentado. No pretendas que lo hagan todo por ti, así nunca vas a aprender. Por otro lado, recorrer el objeto con un bucle `for ... in` parece lo adecuado. Saludos

Comment: En la pregunta se especifica que no se puede emplear los métodos: Values, Key & Entries. Y vos en la respuesta utilizar un bucle For...in, pero luego... ¿no estas empleando Object.keys(obj)? Te agradecería tu respuesta lo más detallada posible. Para aprender. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recorre con un `for...in` y vas creando un nuevo objeto donde la clave es el valor y el valor es la clave. Por ejemplo:

```js
const obj = { nombre: "Homero", apellido: "Simpson" }

function intercambio(obj){
    const result = {}
    for(let key in obj){
        result[obj[key]] = key
    }
    return result
}

console.log(intercambio(obj))
```

Ten en cuenta que esto solo es factible cuando tanto tus claves cómo tus valores son strings.

Comment: Jaime, evita responder a preguntas que no muestran un mínimo de esfuerzo. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Jaime, me faltaba lo del result[obj[key]]

Comment: Gracias @MauricioContreras. Me lo pensé para responderla, pero me dije que como había pensado en `Object (values, keys, entries)` y además eran 3 líneas, había hecho el intento de responderla. De cualquier manera las evitaré.

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar mejor la respuesta? [Riverplatense](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/317581/riverplatense) no la entiende.